# Spring RESTFul Request mapping not working in CHROME (works in IE)

Tags: java, spring, restful-url

The below method returns data in IE but not in Chrome or firefox.

If I access this RestFul webservice url in Chrome/Firefox it just goes in to a loop and brings the whole application down.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/data/{userRecId}/{requestedBy}/{lanId}/{medicalBoardId}/{currentModuleId}/{asOfDate}/{includeStatusNotStarted}")
public ModelAndView getKnowledgePageBean(
        @PathVariable("userRecId") String userRecId,
        @PathVariable("requestedBy") String requestedBy,
        @PathVariable("lanId") String lanId,
        @PathVariable("medicalBoardId") String medicalBoardId,
        @PathVariable("currentModuleId") long currentModuleId,
        @PathVariable("asOfDate") String asOfDate,
        @PathVariable("includeStatusNotStarted") String includeStatusNotStarted) {

    KnowledgeData knowledgeData = new KnowledgeData();
    try {
        knowledgeData = portfolioRestSvc.getKnowledgeData(userRecId,
                requestedBy, lanId, medicalBoardId, currentModuleId,
                asOfDate, includeStatusNotStarted);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ModelAndView(XML_VIEW_NAME, "knowledgeXml", knowledgeData);
}
```

Comment: Could you say what request URL you use ?

Comment: It is HTTP request URL. http://localhost:9080/xxxx/yyyy/data/{userRecId}/{requestedBy}/{lanId}/{medicalBoardId}/{currentModuleId}/{asOfDate}/{includeStatusNotStarted}

Comment: Please use a debugger (or logging) to control what parameters you actually receive in your controller.